# ESRI Field Names?

Tags: data, fields-attributes

A shapefile I retrieved from the Pennsylvania Redistricting site contains field names like `TAPERSONS, TA1RACE. TAWHITEALN. TABLACKALN...` or `VAPERSONS, VA1RAC, VAWHITEALN...`

Some online forensics suggest that these are some kind of ESRI-supplied field names. However, I can't find a data model or codebook that describe the field definitions. I'd rather not try to guess what they mean, though the names suggest demographic data.

Can someone point me to a place where I can find the definitions?

Answer (score 14):

Your field names seem to be linked to CENSUS data (very similar to [this file](https://ulstercountyny.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2010rawmunicipalpopdata.xls) )

@Map_man answer will lead you to the source of your data, to be sure.

See here some metadata that seem to fit : https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/ba931cd7a8f341ed9486a41c6f6798d4/info/metadata/metadata.xml?format=default&output=html

> ```
> Attribute Label: ID
> Attribute Definition: Unique identifying number for each record.
>
> Attribute Label: STFID
> Attribute Definition: Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) code. State + County + Tract + Block number
>
> Attribute Label: BLKGRP
> Attribute Definition: Block group number.
>
> Attribute Label: TAPERSONS
> Attribute Definition: Total 2000 population for a block group.
>
> Attribute Label: TA1RACE
> Attribute Definition: Total number of people identifying themselves as being only one race.
>
> Attribute Label: TAWHITE
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as only White.
>
> Attribute Label: TABLACK
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as only Black.
>
> Attribute Label: TAAMERIND
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as only American Indian, Eskimo, or Aleut.
>
> Attribute Label: TAASIAN
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as only Asian.
>
> Attribute Label: TAHAWPAC
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as only Hawaiian/Pacific Islander.
>
> Attribute Label: TA1OTHER
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to a race other than white, black, American Indian, or Asian.
>
> Attribute Label: TA2MRACE
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to more than one race.
>
> Attribute Label: TA2RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to two races.
>
> Attribute Label: TA3RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to three races.
>
> Attribute Label: TA5RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to five races.
>
> Attribute Label: TA6RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identified as belonging to six races.
>
> Attribute Label: TNTOTAL
> Attribute Definition: Total 2000 population for a block group.
>
> Attribute Label: TNHISPANIC
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identifying themselves as Hispanic.
>
> Attribute Label: TNNONHISP
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identifying themselves as Non-Hispanic.
>
> Attribute Label: TN1RACE
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to one race.
>
> Attribute Label: TNWHITE
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as being White.
>
> Attribute Label: TNBLACK
> Attribute Definition: Number of non-hispanic people identified as being Black.
>
> Attribute Label: TNAMINAKN
> Attribute Definition: Number of non-hispanic people identified as being American Indian, Eskimo, or Aleut.
>
> Attribute Label: TNASIAN
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as being Asian.
>
> Attribute Label: TNHAWOP
> Attribute Definition: Number of non-hispanic people identified as being Hawaiian or Pacific Islander.
>
> Attribute Label: TNOTHER
> Attribute Definition: Number of non-hispanic people identified as being White, Black, American Indian, or Asian.
>
> Attribute Label: TN2MRACE
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 2 or more races.
>
> Attribute Label: TN2RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 2 races.
>
> Attribute Label: TN3RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 3 races.
>
> Attribute Label: TN4RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 4 races.
>
> Attribute Label: TN5RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 5 races.
>
> Attribute Label: TN6RACES
> Attribute Definition: Number of Non-Hispanic people identified as belonging to 6 races.
>
> Attribute Label: ALLAFAM
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identifying themselves as being of African American descent.
>
> Attribute Label: ALLAMIND
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identifying themselves as being of American Indian descent.
>
> Attribute Label: ALLASIAN
> Attribute Definition: Number of people identifying themselves as being of Non-Hispanic descent.
> ```

Comment: Based on this answer, I did further searches and came up with this: https://www.muni.org/Departments/Assembly/Documents/Census_Fields_2010_040911.pdf   . The data fields appear to be demographic data from the 2010 census. This table covered all the variables in my file.

Answer (score 5):

Esri provides guidelines on naming conventions, but not the content of the names themselves. For example, shapefiles have a cap of 10 characters, raster image filenames cap out at 13 characters, neither should have spaces....

Your answer *likely* won't come from an Esri site. You should dig into the dataset and contact the original owners for their metadata, for an exact answer. Usually documents like this come with a README.txt file.

Esri does have the [Local Government Information Model](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/local-government-information-model/) (LGIM) that gives [some recommendations](https://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/local-government-information-model/get-started/DataDictionary/DataDictionary.htm) for naming common objects. That might give a little guidance, but again--the dataset owner could have made their own internal rules.